# ASP.NET MVC viewmodels scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

i'm designing my webapps with ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework Code First approach, so i can scaffold my entities in controllers and views; this works perfectly for base entities and 1-N relationships (dropdowns in views).

My question is: is there a "native" way of handling (even complex) viewmodels ?

Currently i'm using AngularJS 1 to resolve this.

my goal is to define database entities + viewmodels and then just scaffold my way to create the complete webapp.

question2 : is there any reference/e-book/tutorial that covers this theme ASP.NET MVC in total? i'm reading o'reilly Entity Framework Code First.

thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand the question at all.  What have you tried so far, what is the issue?  The second question, relating to suggestions for material, isn't relevant to this format.

Comment: thank you for your attention, my goal is to create ASP.NET MVC web applications in an automated way (i'm using visual studio 2015); this is already available ( read: i know how to do this ) for entities and SIMPLE 1-N relationships ( mapped as dropdowns in views), but not if i have to do a CREATE view where i have to insert multiple different entities ( viewmodels ).

"my goal is to define database entities + viewmodels and then just scaffold my way to create the complete webapp."

p.s. for me is relevant.

Comment: Do you really expect someone to formulate an answer to this problem?  It's far too broad a question.  I'm sorry

Comment: Check out Matt Honeycutt's courses on Pluralsight - especially the Application Framework course. https://www.pluralsight.com/authors/matt-honeycutt

Comment: @steve - thank you man ! tomorrow i'll see